# Google Assistant not speaking the welcome text

Tags: actions-on-google

I am in the alpha phase testing of my google action. Now once we speak/type our invocation phrase usually google says "Sure, lets get XYZ" and then starts the skill. But for my alpha testers it is not saying that and also the first welcome phrase that I have in my action is not spoken.

I don't know what to try for this kind of problem.

Comment: Have you added GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME event in the events section of Default Welcome Intent?

Comment: What *does* it do when one of your alpha testers try to start the action?

Comment: @Prisoner it means to invoke the action by using invocation phrase.

Comment: @SatishPandey how do you do that, and actually I am using jovo framework to design logic not any google-action sdk

Comment: Yes, but you're telling us what it doesn't do. What *does* it do for your alpha testers? Is this different from what it does when a developer tests it?

Comment: Ohh, it does same things for both alpha testers and developer.